# Increase ext4 partition size by decreasing Swap memory size in linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ram, swap

I was a newbie while installing linux mint 17.2 in my laptop. So I allocated more than 20GB for my swap memory and 30Gb for ext4 partition. Now only I realized that swap memory is using instead of RAM while running memory overwhelming applications.I have 4GB of DDR3 RAM so no need of this much of swap memory.So I want to add some memory space from swap to Ext4. Is there any idea for deleting or decreasing the swap memory and add that memory to EXT4 partition? The details of my hard disk given bellow .I'm using Linux mint 17.2 64 bit and windows 8 pro with media center 64 bit in dual boot.

```
$parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54757 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
2      106MB   210GB  210GB   primary   ntfs
3      210GB   421GB  211GB   primary   ntfs
4      421GB   750GB  329GB   extended                  lba
7      421GB   451GB  30.0GB  logical   ext4
8      451GB   473GB  22.4GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
5      473GB   579GB  106GB   logical   ntfs
6      579GB   750GB  171GB   logical   ntfs

(parted)
```

If the solution will not effect my windows files then let me know the solution. Actually I found some solutions but most of them are suggesting 'GParted ISO '.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: Questions about other Linux distributions are only off topic, if the solution to the issue is arguably different than it would be in Ubuntu. I don't think this is the case here, since resizing root and swap partitions definitely is the same in Ubuntu and Mint.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: close vote retracted. This should allow you to find 2 more duplicate close votes in the chat room...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Install GParted (available under your Software Center). Run, in a terminal, 'sudo gparted'. Type your password and press ENTER. GParted will open up. Right-click your swap partition and decrease its size to your needs. Be sure that the unallocated space generated by the size decreasing is "before" the swap partition, and not "after".

Now right-click your ext4 partition and select to increase/decrease size. You will be able to increase its size with the unallocated size now.